# Add/update activity date time using webform

Tags: webform-civicrm, activities

Is it possible to use webform to update the activity date and time using webform?

Comment: are we assuming that aid (activity ID) is in the url?

Comment: yes, but how can we add/update time? webform allows only date field

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below please find some screenshots to show you how: note there is an Activity Date and an Activity Time checkbox

[image]

[image]